# Swift error enum with associated value returns incorrect enum literal in switch statement

Tags: swift, enums

This is a slightly confusing issue which I hope someone might be able to shed some light on.

I am using a `Result<T, E: ErrorType>` style enum to capture success or failure of an async call.

I am using another enum to group a number of errors together, some of which have associated values

I have a callback which looks like `Result<Void, MyError> -> Void` 
which I use to pass an error back to the calling code.

Ok, all is simple so far. However, the issue I am seeing is that when I have an error enum with associated values, sometimes the wrong error is printed out at the call site.

I shall try show what I mean via a bit of code:

```
enum Result<T, E: ErrorType> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(E)
}
```

Test 1

```
typealias MyCallback1 = Result<Void, MyError1> -> Void

enum MyError1: ErrorType {
    case A, B, C, D
}

func test1() {
    execute1() { result in
        switch (result) {
        case .Success(_):
            break
        case let .Failure(error):
            print(error)
            break
        }
    }
}

func execute1(callback: MyCallback1) {
    callback(.Failure(.A))
    callback(.Failure(.B))
    callback(.Failure(.C))
    callback(.Failure(.D))
}
```

Test 2

```
typealias MyCallback2 = Result<Void, MyError2> -> Void

enum MyError2: ErrorType {
    case A(String), B, C, D
}

func test2() {
    execute2() { result in
        switch (result) {
        case .Success(_):
            break
        case let .Failure(error):
            print(error)
            break
        }
    }
}

func execute2(callback: MyCallback2) {
    callback(.Failure(.A("a")))
    callback(.Failure(.B))
    callback(.Failure(.C))
    callback(.Failure(.D))
}
```

Test 3

```
typealias MyCallback3 = Result<Void, MyError3> -> Void

enum MyError3: ErrorType {
    case A(String), B, C(String), D
}

func test3() {
    execute3() { result in
        switch (result) {
        case .Success(_):
            break
        case let .Failure(error):
            print(error)
            break
        }
    }
}

func execute3(callback: MyCallback3) {
    callback(.Failure(.A("a")))
    callback(.Failure(.B))
    callback(.Failure(.C("c")))
    callback(.Failure(.D))
}
```

Test 4

```
typealias MyCallback4 = Result<Void, MyError4> -> Void

enum MyError4: ErrorType {
    case A(String), B, C, D(String)
}

func test4() {
    execute4() { result in
        switch (result) {
        case .Success(_):
            break
        case let .Failure(error):
            print(error)
            break
        }
    }
}

func execute4(callback: MyCallback4) {
    callback(.Failure(.A("a")))
    callback(.Failure(.B))
    callback(.Failure(.C))
    callback(.Failure(.D("d")))
}
```

Test 5

```
typealias MyCallback5 = Result<Void, MyError5> -> Void

enum MyError5: ErrorType {
    case A, B, C, D(String)
}

func test5() {
    execute5() { result in
        switch (result) {
        case .Success(_):
            break
        case let .Failure(error):
            print(error)
            break
        }
    }
}

func execute5(callback: MyCallback5) {
    callback(.Failure(.A))
    callback(.Failure(.B))
    callback(.Failure(.C))
    callback(.Failure(.D("d")))
}
```

The results of running the tests are as follows:

```
Test1
A
B
C
D

Test2
A("a")
B
C
D

Test3
A("a")
B
C("c")
B <---- Hmmm?

Test4
A("a")
B
B <---- Hmmm?
D("d")

Test5
A
B
C
D("d")
```

I am at a bit of a loss understanding why tests 3 and 4 print the results they do. Could any kind person please enlighten me.

Kind regards

Edit: Some additional information. 
I am using XCode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001).

```
xcrun swift -version
Apple Swift version 2.0 (swiftlang-700.0.59 clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
```

I am seeing this behaviour in both the playground and in code running on the simulator

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results with Xcode 7.2. All tests print A, B, C, D (plus some associated values).

Comment: Many thanks for checking that for me Martin. I do appreciate it. Unfortunately our build server is not up to date with 7.2 yet so I'm stuck with this earlier version for now. I'll take a look through the change notes to see if I can find anything that explains the difference in what I'm seeing

Comment: For any other soul that happens upon this stack overflow posting, I have since been able to try in XCode 7.1 (swift 2.1) and do not see this issue so it looks like it was isolated to that particular build of swift shipped with XCode 7.0.1.